# Is this a meaningful generalization of `scan`s for arbitrary ADTs?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, type-theory

I've been thinking how one could generalize `scanl` to arbitrary ADTs. The Prelude approach is just to treat everything as a list (i.e., `Foldable`) and apply the `scanl` on the flatened view of the structure. Instead, I tend to think of `scanl` as an operation that passes a state from each node of the tree to its children, while applying a monoidal op as it travels down from root to the leaves. So, for example, on `Data.Tree`, we have:

```
scan :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> Tree b
scan fn init (Node element children) 
    = Node (fn init element) 
        $ map (treeScan fn (fn init element)) children
```

So that, for example:

```
main = do
    prettyPrint $ scan (+) 0 $
        Node 1 [
            Node 1 [
                Node 1 [], 
                Node 1 []],
            Node 1 [
                Node 1 [], 
                Node 1 []]]
```

Results in:

```
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 3
|  |
|  `- 3
|
`- 2
   |
   +- 3
   |
   `- 3
```

Which is the same as applying `scanl` through each path of the tree independently, preserving the original structure.

The question is rather simple: is this a meaningful generalization? I.e., is it commonly used, with a categorical explanation, and perhaps with a different name?

Comment: Well, there's [`scanl1Of`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:scanl1Of). With a suitable `Traversal` this might do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this extended `scanl` should pass the same `init` to all children, as done above, or chain them as `fold` does.

Comment: **chi**'s `scanl` is `scan :: Traversable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> f b; scan f z a = evalState (traverse (\x -> modify (flip f x) >> get) a) z`.

Answer (score 1):

If you move to the fixpoint-of-functors "generic" representation of data, you can view a scan (or rather its slight generalization, a `mapAccum`) as a special type of generic fold.

Here's some code that sketches a pattern that you should be able to continue:

```
data Fix f a = Roll (f a (Fix f a))

cata :: Functor (f a) => (f a b -> b) -> Fix f a -> b
cata alg (Roll x) = alg $ fmap (cata alg) x

scan :: Functor (f a) => (f a (acc, Fix f b) -> (acc, f b (Fix f b))) -> Fix f a -> Fix f b
scan alg = snd . cata (fmap Roll . alg)

data ListF a b = NilF | ConsF a b deriving Functor

scanAlgList f z NilF = (z, NilF)
scanAlgList f z (ConsF a (acc,b)) =
            let val = f a acc
            in (val, ConsF val b)

data TreeF a b = LeafF a | BranchF a b b deriving Functor

scanAlgTree f (LeafF x) = (x, LeafF x)
scanAlgTree f (BranchF v (accL,l) (accR,r)) =
            let val = f v accL accR
            in (val, BranchF v l r)
```

Gibbons discusses this in passing in his [article](https://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/horners-rule/) on Horners rule. He actually first described such things as "downward accumulations" in an [article from 1992](https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/2292/3464/TR061.pdf?sequence=2) on "Upwards and Downwards Accumulations on Trees".